“A man will not be asked about why he beat his wife.” - what is its authenticity and interpretation?
in Mishkat al-Masabih 3268 it says ‘Umar reported the Prophet as saying,

لا يسأل الرجل فيما ضرب امرأته عليه
“A man will not be asked about why he beat his wife.”

Abu Dawud and Ibn Majah transmitted it. idk if it sahih or not

The hadith was classed as Saheeh by al-Hakim and Hassan by Zubair Ali Zai.
Others like  al-Albani and al-Arnaa’oot and Ahmad Shakir have classed it is as Da'eef.
As for its meaning: A man is permitted to beat his wife under certain circumstances, which is also evident from the Quran, other authentic Ahadith and from Ijma':

واللاتي تخافون نشوزهن فعظوهن واهجروهن في المضاجع واضربوهن فإن أطعنكم فلا تبغوا عليهن سبيلا
But those [wives] from whom you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist], forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you [once more], seek no means against them.
— Quran 4:34


‏ فإن فعلن فاهجروهن في المضاجع واضربوهن ضربا غير مبرح فإن أطعنكم فلا تبغوا عليهن سبيلا
If they do that, then forsake them in their beds and hit them, but without causing injury or leaving a mark. If they obey you, then do not seek means of annoyance against them.
— Ibn Majah

The hadith in the question means that as long as the husband exercises this within the law he will not be sinful for it, and will not be questioned about it by Allah on the day of Judgement.
And also that if a man beats his wife then other people should not ask him the reason since that is an invasion of privacy, it would lead to divulging the offense for which the wife was punished which harms her reputation and leads to censure by others - whereas she should not be harmed any further when she has returned to obedience. It is also possible that the reason is such that talking about it is against modesty, such as disobedience in sexual matters.
The beating must however be light and within limits and can only be done if there is a valid reason for it as evident from other texts. If the beating is established to be done in oppression then the husband will be sinful and will be stopped, see What is the punishment for beating up your wife without a valid reason?.

I've noticed there are two different wordings of this hadith recorded; "لاَ يُسْأَلُ الرَّجُلُ فِيمَا ضَرَبَ امْرَأَتَهُ" and "لاَ يُسْأَلُ الرَّجُلُ فِيمَ يَضْرِبُ امْرَأَتَهُ"; I am not fluent in Arabic to know if this changes the meaning, but I've also seen two different translations between "A man will not be asked..." (implying that he will not be held accountable even on the Day of Judgement), vs "A man should not be asked..." (implying that it's improper to bring up the topic in this world). Probably worth clarifying this.

Yes, both interpretations of the hadith exist. That is why I have written that 'he will not be sinful' and that 'he should not be asked'.

thank you so much umh
